# Log username of who restarts a service

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-event-log, windows-service

I'm looking for a simple way to log the username of someone that restarts a service on a server. This was possible in 2003, but I do not see a possibility in 2008 and 2012.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct.  Event Viewer > System tab the Service Control Manager no longer logs who starts and stops a Service. You'll only see a message like ***The Workstation service entered the running state.*** but nothing about what user/process/service caused it to start.

To audit who is starting and stopping services in Windows Server 2008 and later, you'll need to do some manual work as detailed here:

- IT Pro Today, Randy Franklin Smith, 2002-04-16, [*Access Denied: Auditing Users Who Might Be Starting and Stopping Services*](http://www.itprotoday.com/systems-management/access-denied-auditing-users-who-might-be-starting-and-stopping-services) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/MmtwU).)

This is the method I have used to audit who is starting and stopping services on critical servers. Below is the steps to take to Audit your desired Service on a Windows Server. Please refer to the link for additional information.

> To reach the security templates, log on to the server and open the Microsoft Management Console (MMC) Security Templates snap-in. To create a new template, right-click on the security templates path. Select New Template, click System Services, then double-click the appropriate service (i.e., Telnet). Select the Define this policy setting in the template check box, then click Edit Security to open the Security for Telnet dialog box that Figure 1 shows. This dialog box contains the service's ACL, which you can use to fine-tune who has start and stop authority. (For more information about permission to start and stop services, see "Troubleshooting problems with the Start, stop and pause permission," March 2002, InstantDoc ID 23964.)
>
> Click Advanced, then select the Auditing tab in the Access Control
>   Settings for Telnet dialog box, which Figure 2 shows. As you can see,
>   no auditing is currently enabled on the Telnet service because
>   auditing isn't enabled by default. Click Add, then add an entry to
>   track successful start and stop events that members of Everyone
>   initiate, as Figure 3 shows. Close all the dialog boxes, then save the
>   template. Import the template into the MMC Security Configuration and
>   Analysis snap-in, then apply the template. Now, you can check the
>   Security log for event ID 560 (success audit: object open), where
>   Object Type is SERVICE OBJECT, the Object Name is the short name of
>   the service you're monitoring (in the case of the Telnet Service,
>   TlntSvr), and the logged accesses include Start the service and Stop
>   the service. In the example that Figure 4 shows, you can see that Joe
>   stopped the Telnet service.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Active Directory domain you can do this with domain group policy:

1. Make a GPO and apply it to the server concerned.
2. Edit it, go to `Computer Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > System Services > whatever service` (you need to specify the service, and can't very easily apply this to *all* services)
3. **Define this policy setting** and choose the appropriate startup mode (to whatever it is by default). Click **Edit Security**, **Advanced**, **Auditing** tab
4. Add auditing entries to cover the users and actions you want to log.
5. I'm not sure if you additionally need to enable anything under `Computer Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Audit Policy` - I have not found any proper documentation one way or another  but know that if you are setting auditing on files, for instance, you need to enable object access auditing else it doesn't work.

Actions on services should then be logged in the Security event log on the server.